# Developing an existing R package with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

As the title probably says, I have an R package which has been developed already mostly in C.
Now that I'm trying to add some new stuff to the package, I'm not comfortable with C anymore and I'm willing to use Rcpp.

I have also developed my new functions in Rcpp, but I have no idea how to link these two codes.

Could you please give a hint where to start ?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the [documentation](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html)?  Dirk has made an extraordinary effort in documenting how to use Rcpp.

Comment: Just as you use the letter "C" in your text does not justify to add the C-language tag.

Comment: By the way, you had it three times as Rccp. It is Rcpp.  As in 'plus plus', not 'c c'.

Answer (score 1):

There are now over 400 packages on CRAN which use Rcpp.  A fairly large number of these were "converts".  You could look at some of these---many of use find working examples to be very helpful complements to documentation.

And there is no magic:  just do the few steps needed to create a *working Rcpp package* (for which calling `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` is possibly the easiest route) and carry the required pieces (from `DESCRIPTION`, `NAMESPACE`, `src/Makevars*`, ...) over to your existing package.

Comment: Thanks for your "polite" respond. 

But how is that gonna work if I put all my *.c and *.cpp in src folder of the package ?. In addition I meant, how can I call a function which has been developed in Rcpp from another C function?

Comment: You are overcomplicating things.   As I said, just start with a near-empty Rcpp package, then add a C.  *There is no magic*.  R knows what to do with C files, and R knows what to do with C++, _i.e._ Rcpp (the package) has several C++ files and one C file in `src/`.

Comment: Thanks, and how can I call a function which has been developed in Rcpp from another C function?

Comment: Search StackOverflow or Google on 'how to call C++ code from C', and learn about `extern "C"`.  This question no longer has anything to do with Rcpp proper.